# Best way to deform a cylinder

Tags: modeling, pose-mode

I'm still fairly new to Blender, please advice:

This is not a completed or rigged model, I feel I'm still blocking the robot. I was trying to pose the robot without any rig, so I used proportional editing to move the arms and neck. They deformed, and I wonder if it's do to low polygon count. Should I add more cuts?

I'm uploading the models to Hitrecord, which is a collaborative platform, feel free to remix the models (I uploaded the whole process) but please resubmit to the platform if you make any changes to it (rig, materials, renders)
https://hitrecord.org/records/3966944

[image: before deformation][image: after deformation]

Comment: Do you want to animate the result?

Comment: if you're supposed to give several poses to your character you should seriously think about parenting it to an armature, it will save you time

Comment: @RobinBetts not sure, I think I want to 3D print it first (without the cables), not sure about animating, I have never animated before.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks, do you think deformation by spline is suggested or should I use regular armature? I was told B-bones were a good fit for cylinder meshes like these.